# Create an ObjectNode from JSON string

Tags: java, json, jackson

How do I create a ObjectNode from a string using Jackson?

I tried:

```
ObjectNode json = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{}", ObjectNode.class);
```

But get

> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "type": jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.Symbol#setType(1 params) vs jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.Symbol#setType(1 params)

I want to be able to read a JSON string the add/modify some values.

Answer (score 11):

Firstly, the error message suggests you're tying to build a `jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.ObjectNode`, whereas I'm guessing you actually intended to build a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode` (for Jackson 2.x). Check your imports.

However, if all you want to do is build an empty `ObjectNode`, then just use

```
JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode()
```

If for some reason you *really* want to do it by parsing an empty JSON object, then use this:

```
ObjectNode json = (ObjectNode) new ObjectMapper().readTree("{}");
```

But that's just unpleasant.

Comment: Thanks, yea I just noticed the import was wrong... *sigh*

Answer (score 11):

You are using the wrong import.

It should be

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
```

Not:

```
jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.ObjectNode
```